# Incongruent visual appearance of New Menu Bar

Tags: discussion, top-bar

This is my first post in meta and I would like to voice my concern over the new menu bar. I find it looks very **bad**. To make this a bit more accurate:

- The color palette does not integrate well with *any* of the popular stackExchange sites.
- The color palette does not integrate well with popular browser color schemes (which mostly use light colors) - making the bar a visually disruptive high contrast feature smack in between your address bar and content.
- Color-wise the bar is not even congruent with itself - blue, white, black, green, red, gray doesn't sound like a particularly well-elaborated mix.

I would be happy to get your approval for my concern or to hear about any explanation why the current visual appearance was chosen.

Comment: Wait a week to get used to it, then see if you still have the same concerns. It took me a couple of days too.

Comment: So your issue is only with the color of the bar?

Comment: And what will you do with that explanation? What does it change? It is the way it is. Because someone thought it will be good for their business to do it that way. If you want some specific changes or functionalities, why not to ask for them directly?

Comment: Sites change. Even big Google totally changed its design over the years. It's bad only because you got used to the old design.

Comment: Do you really expect people to design websites according to the color palette of the users browsers???

Comment: Also, as for why the current design was chosen, Stack Exchange hired a professional [graphic designer](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/3/jin) who [is working in the web design field since 1995](http://www.8164.org/about/) - it's not just a random choice.

Comment: Not every professional design is necessarily great. Colour and design are quite subjective but I also don't think current colour scheme is very well matched. Also, this design looks a bit dated...

Comment: I find the bottom of the SE logo and the Inbox and Achievements symbols fade into the background too much to be clear.

Comment: +1000 and please, do hire some guy who is not blind and understand colors.

Comment: It matches the colopr pattern I use in my browser very well...

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd yes sites change over time, but changes are usually to something better.

Comment: Top bar hover makes background goes from black to gray. It's just a complete WTF!? moment.

Comment: +1! Yes, change is sometimes disruptive and takes a while to get used to, but there is no denying that the colour scheme, and style is something straight out of 1995 ^^. It is so dated, and the dark appearance actually makes it look like text is missing. There is no need for the background of the header to be this dark.

Comment: Also... This bar has been in beta on meta for a very long time. How is it that you're only now commenting on it?

Comment: @danielhanly.com I'm not particularly interested in anything but SO, so I don't usually care for rest of the sites.

Comment: @TsSkTo that was also my reaction to new "design"

Comment: @danielhanly.com Most people aren't on meta regularly; why should they

Comment: I must admit, I love the functionality of the new bar but hate the look of it

Comment: so that's how a "professional" design looks like! ... I thought I had a problem with my video card...

Comment: @mpapec "better" is subjective, like taste. I love shnitzel and humus, you love bacon and chips (just example of course ;)). Each and his own and it's impossible to reach something acceptable by everyone.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd when I look at quantity of recent meta questions it looks like bacon and cheeps are somehow dominating over other tastes.

Comment: @mpapec that's because people get used to something and old habits die hard. If you really want to check this, we'll have to run a poll for the new users/visitors and ask them what they think.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I don't mind visual change as long as I can change that somewhere in personal preferences. And, yes it would be ineteresting to check poll results.

Comment: @mpapec People only complain when they don't like something

Comment: I like the new functionality of toolbar! I hate how it looks. It really is terrible, I feel like I'm not sure what's going on across my StackExchange network. The colour layout should be either theme-able or match the website layout at least. Just making it lighter in Google Chrome developer panel is an improvement. @ShaWizDowArd Existing user's opinion are just as valid as new user's, that's like saying someone can't comment on a car's dashboard layout because they're used to/have used another one.

Comment: Won't somebody please think of the children? - Really guys a black toolbar with grey text on it isn't very readable!

Comment: @Andy Yeah, who would put a black bar on a modern website?!? [Oh, wait](http://switchedonmedia.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/google-black-bar-530x225.png). And it is well-known how much users hate black navigation bars! [Oh. Right.](http://lifehacker.com/proper-menubar-brings-back-googles-trusty-black-bar-1449031481) I am not suggesting you don't know what you're talking about, but I am noticing that StackOverflow didn't hire **you** to design the menu bar, nor did Google. Maybe someone other company is hiring? [Like these guys](http://www.flickr.com/jobs/)? Erm...